# trying to construct a KML file to display lat long grid and sample points

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have a complicated KML file to construct

I need to draw 4 latitude lines at:

```
52.33812724 52.33820125 52.33827526 52.33834927
```

and 88 longitude lines at :

```
-106.285181641440000
-106.285155147508000
-106.285128653577000
-106.285102159645000
-106.285075665714000
-106.285049171782000
-106.285022677851000
-106.284996183919000
-106.284969689988000
-106.284943196056000
-106.284916702125000
-106.284890208193000
-106.284863714261000
-106.284837220330000
-106.284810726398000
-106.284784232467000
-106.284757738535000
-106.284731244604000
-106.284704750672000
-106.284678256741000
-106.284651762809000
-106.284625268878000
-106.284598774946000
-106.284572281015000
-106.284545787083000
-106.284519293152000
-106.284492799220000
-106.284466305289000
-106.284439811357000
-106.284413317426000
-106.284386823494000
-106.284360329563000
-106.284333835631000
-106.284307341700000
-106.284280847768000
-106.284254353837000
-106.284227859905000
-106.284201365973000
-106.284174872042000
-106.284148378110000
-106.284121884179000
-106.284095390247000
-106.284068896316000
-106.284042402384000
-106.284015908453000
-106.283989414521000
-106.283962920590000
-106.283936426658000
-106.283909932727000
-106.283883438795000
-106.283856944864000
-106.283830450932000
-106.283803957001000
-106.283777463069000
-106.283750969138000
-106.283724475206000
-106.283697981275000
-106.283671487343000
-106.283644993412000
-106.283618499480000
-106.283592005549000
-106.283565511617000
-106.283539017686000
-106.283512523754000
-106.283486029823000
-106.283459535891000
-106.283433041960000
-106.283406548028000
-106.283380054097000
-106.283353560165000
-106.283327066234000
-106.283300572302000
-106.283274078371000
-106.283247584439000
-106.283221090508000
-106.283194596576000
-106.283168102645000
-106.283141608713000
-106.283115114781000
-106.283088620850000
-106.283062126918000
-106.283035632987000
-106.283009139056000
-106.282982645124000
-106.282956151193000
-106.282929657261000
-106.282903163330000
-106.282876669398000
-106.282903163330000
```

as well as a series of sample points that I would like to be a simple red dot

that look like this:

```
**Lat                     Long
52.338129160000000000   -106.28331185333300
52.338129123333300000   -106.28330918666700
52.338129173333300000   -106.28330423833300
52.338129196666700000   -106.28330190333300
52.338129283333300000   -106.28329948000000
52.338129258333300000   -106.28329752166700
52.338129241666700000   -106.28329308000000**
```

so far I have this which doesn't even plot the points

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">

<Document>

<Placemark>

    <Point>

        <coordinates>52.338344750000000,-106.285246311667000,0</coordinates>

    </Point>

</Placemark>

<Placemark>

    <Point>

        <coordinates>52.338129160000000,-106.283311853333000,0</coordinates>

    </Point>

</Placemark>

<Placemark>

    <Point>

        <coordinates>52.338272905000000,-106.284936286667000,0</coordinates>

    </Point>

</Placemark>

</Document>

</kml>
```

what i am wondering is there any tools to build KML files instead of hand coding them. Is there anything like the ESRI tools I have seen where you can draw lines points shaps etc.

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to create XY points and import it into whatever CAD/GIS program you have.

Comment: ok and export them as a KML ? can esri do that I'll have a look I have arcgis 10.1

Comment: ArcGIS can certainly export to KML, as can most other GIS software. Note that Google Earth PRO can import many formats to create KML layers. Howver, the scale you are working on (looks like sub-meter) is better handled by CAD programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably create the KML using Google Earth (GE) Pro.

Here is the first line:

```
    <Placemark>
    <name>Untitled Path</name>
    <LineString>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <coordinates>
            -106.283830450932,52.33812724,0 -106.283803957001,52.33812724,0 -106.283777463069,52.33812724,0 -106.283750969138,52.33812724,0 -106.283724475206,52.33812724,0 -106.283697981275,52.33812724,0 -106.283671487343,52.33812724,0 -106.283644993412,52.33812724,0 -106.28361849948,52.33812724,0 -106.283592005549,52.33812724,0 -106.283565511617,52.33812724,0 -106.283539017686,52.33812724,0 -106.283512523754,52.33812724,0 -106.283486029823,52.33812724,0 -106.283459535891,52.33812724,0 -106.28343304196,52.33812724,0 -106.283406548028,52.33812724,0 -106.283380054097,52.33812724,0 -106.283353560165,52.33812724,0 -106.283327066234,52.33812724,0 -106.283300572302,52.33812724,0 -106.283274078371,52.33812724,0 -106.283247584439,52.33812724,0 -106.283221090508,52.33812724,0 -106.283194596576,52.33812724,0 -106.283168102645,52.33812724,0 -106.283141608713,52.33812724,0 -106.283115114781,52.33812724,0 -106.28308862085,52.33812724,0 -106.283062126918,52.33812724,0 -106.283035632987,52.33812724,0 -106.283009139056,52.33812724,0 -106.282982645124,52.33812724,0 -106.282956151193,52.33812724,0 -106.282929657261,52.33812724,0 -106.28290316333,52.33812724,0 -106.282876669398,52.33812724,0 -106.28290316333,52.33812724,0 
        </coordinates>
    </LineString>
</Placemark>
```

You can copy the text and paste it to GE Temporary Places.

Use a text editor and replace the Lat in the above with the next one, repeat for all four.

Note that you can copy/paste KML from GE - just right click an object and Copy to get the object's KML. You can paste the code to an editor. After eiting paste KML you create into a GE folder (right click Paste.)

To add points just add one in GE, copy the KML, and massage it an editor making changes to meet your needs. If you have a lot of points create an X,Y file and import it into GE.

X,Y,Z
-106.283830450932000,52.33812724,0 
-106.283803957001000,52.33812724,0 
-106.283777463069000,52.33812724,0 
-106.283750969138000,52.33812724,0 
-106.283724475206000,52.33812724,0 
-106.283697981275000,52.33812724,0 
...

I have the Z here as I used it to create the line Placemark, not needed for X,Y import.

You can also work with files instead of the clipboard.

A useful editor would be Visual Studio Code or Notepad++ - both have support for XML formatted data.

Comment: Note that X=Long, Y=Lat in the above post. GE coordinates are XYZ. Never see Z used, but....